# Flutter - Animation Text Fade transition

Tags: animation, flutter

i wanna make a fade transition on two text , what i mean the value change from text to another by animation ... for example one .. two .. and repeat this value again and again

and that's what i tried to make

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        child: FadeTransition(
          opacity: controller2,
          child: Text('Breathe in ',textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30,),),
        ),
        color: Colors.red,


 ),
```

How Can I Achieve This ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can solve this using `AnimatedOpacity`, where it automatically animates, fading opacity in and out.

This sample code stacks 2 widgets, one red and one black, alternating which one have full opacity.

```
double opacity = 1.0;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  changeOpacity();
}

changeOpacity() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    setState(() {
      opacity = opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
      changeOpacity();
    });
  });
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: opacity,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: opacity == 1 ? 0 : 1,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ]
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work ... What i mean is change the text from value "one" to another value "two" but automaticaly by animation such as gif counter but applied in text not number

Comment: Replacing the `Container`'s with your text isn't near what you want? Try replacing `Container(
          color: Colors.black,
        )` for `Text("One")` and `Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),` for `Text("Two")`

Comment: oh Thank you so much This what i tried to achieve , it works fine :)

Comment: ohh i'm sorry but i have a liitle problem i have another animation in the same class and by this function it doesn't work fine

Comment: There is no problem having mulitple animations in the same widget, it's problably some conflict in your own code. Put one animation to work, then put a second one keeping the first one working.

Comment: i'm using animator package and the animation of my first widget doesn't reverse  i need to achieve this and the problem caused by this line Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () when i comment it the animation of my first widget works fine but the text doesn't repeat itself

Comment: @EvaldoBratti by any chance, you know how to solve this? It's a transition of the text in the same list, instead of text across list.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314514/animation-text-transition-upon-button-press